# FInd with Array TypeOrm

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a Mysql DataBase, and I need to make a consult for return all the relations (I'm consulting to relation table) that matches with an array of Ids, so for that I'll receive the array by body and I'm planing do the next consult:

```
const taskRelationFound = await getRepository(TaskRelation).findOne({ where: { ProjectId: ProjectIds , IsActive: true } });
```

it is into a async method, and the value of projectsIds is the next: `[ "ccb79423-ed2b-4650-acb4-567c5e2a6cff", "68ff86e2-1c81-4487-bc7e-dddf1507f99e" ]`

ProjectIds is an array with all the Id's where I'm looking for get the relations where each Id's matches with the ProjectId column, but I'm getting an error in the consult, and I'm not sure why

My entity works with this structure:

```
   TaskRelationId: string;
    TaskId: string;
    UserId: string;
    ProjectId: string;
    IsResponsable: boolean;
    IsActive: boolean;
```

so how can I get all relations where ProjectId Matches with any ProjectId that I'm giving throw the array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you want to apply the `where` clause to an array `projectIds`, you need to use `In` operator as follows -

```
import { In } from 'typeorm';
const taskRelationFound = await getRepository(TaskRelation).findOne({ where: { ProjectId: In(ProjectIds) , IsActive: true } });
```

Comment: How to do this with query builder?

Comment: This GitHub issue link will be of help: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1239 ..It illustrates how to construct such queries using a query builder